# Problems reloading udev rules while installing snaps in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: snap, udev

I'm trying to install the snap application *whatsdesk* on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and I keep getting the following errors:

```
$ sudo snap install whatsdesk
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "whatsdesk" (17) security profiles (cannot setup udev for snap "whatsdesk": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Setup snap "whatsdesk" (17) security profiles (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect whatsdesk:opengl to core:opengl (cannot setup udev for snap "whatsdesk": cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
- Connect whatsdesk:opengl to core:opengl (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 2
udev output:
)
```

I've been googling around for similar problems but the only similar problem I have seen is in the [snnapd forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-setup-udev-for-snap-core-cannot-reload-udev-rules/9633/2) but not solution appears there.